# Locked vs Closed

Tags: support, discussion, locked-posts

Whats the difference between locked and closed API wise. What I mean is why is this question locked:
https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/4755/should-i-get-a-credit-card-closed

But this one closed:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5873/good-and-bad-things-about-internet-privacy-closed

Even though on both sites the questions have [closed] after them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distinction is somewhat subtle.

Locked questions prevent *all* activity on the question (new answers, edits, votes, etc.).

Closed questions prevent new answers, but the question (and existing answers) can still be edited and voted upon.

Your Money.SE question has been merged, which looks like a close **and** lock from the API as merging wasn't around when the API v1 interface was frozen.